# Are the new iOS iPhoto help controls a standard class?

Tags: ios

The new iPhoto for iOS has a [help overlay](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11615635/iphoto.png) that includes controls that point at/describe the individual affordances.

Is this a standard control type that I don't know about, or something that has to be built by hand?

Comment: On an unrelated note, I hate the font. Looks too much like _Comic Sans_ to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No these are private libraries. But I wish there would be a developer API for that.
I've also seen the help overlays in GarageBand for iOS.

Comment: Oh, well. (And since the comment needs more characters, I'll add that the ones in GarageBand are worse: I hate the dumb skeuomorphic ragged edged stuff.)